# OOo Draw Import / Export Visio Diagrams

Tags: openoffice, microsoft-visio

Just read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/29060/visio-alternatives) by Jason S and it reminded me that I'm interested in a means of importing / exporting between Visio & OOo Draw (primarily using OOo to edit Visio files).

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting your Visio 2003 files to SVG. That's the only way that might work. I know Visio can open SVGs and convert them into a Visio binary file.

Maybe the SVG files created by Visio can be read by OOo Draw.

Comment: no go on opening the svg in OOo Draw -  it kicks over to Writer.  Gonna do some googling about getting svg into Draw

Comment: this looks promising: http://www.ipd.uka.de/~hauma/svg-import/

Comment: well, that kinda worked.  The text is a little screwed up but still, I think this a workable solution

Comment: Thank you, kind sir :). I'm only sorry this wasn't the most straightforward solution possible.

Answer (score 3):

Open Office does not support importing / exporting to Visio.  There have been several attempts, including one recently during Google's Summer of Code, but thus far all have been left fairly incomplete.

If you want to use another application other than Visio, but still be Visio-compatible, I'd recommend [Lucidchart](http://www.lucidchart.com).  It can import .vsd and .vdx files and also export back to .vdx.

Answer (score 0):

The old Visio binary format is not well-known, and as far as I can remember, there's no real documentation on it... No-one has yet reverse-engineered it...

The new Visio XML format (.VDX) is better known, and there are some VDX->SVG converters around. If you can get the files saved as Visio XML, then you might have more luck.

(Disclaimer: this was the state of play about a year ago, from my memory. Some things might have changed since then...)

Comment: hmmmm - worth seeing what can be done with a vdx at least