# Viewing and editing .vsd files

Tags: microsoft-visio

What free programs can I use to view **and** edit .vsd files?

I am working with someone that does not switch to Visio and while I could use Microsoft's [Visio Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21701) to see what it's sent me, I cannot make any changes and send them back with this.

I am aware of question *[Visio alternatives](https://superuser.com/questions/29060/visio-alternatives)*, but it does not address whether or not any of them can open Visio files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know and am aware there are no other products that edit Visio files, because it is totally proprietary file format.  [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) is the closest you will come, but again last I used it, it didn't open Visio files.

Comment: If you would like to convert/embed .vsd files into Dia/.dia format: Have a look at vsd2svg. It's available for free from http://dia-installer.de/vsd2svg

Answer (score 2):

In fact, Corel Draw can import vsd-files and make them editable as a vector drawing. All text is converted to curves though. I have tested this in Corel Draw X5, I don't know if other (earlier) versions can do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Lucidchart](http://www.lucidchart.com) which is a web-based [Visio alternative](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/tour/visio_alternative).  It can import .vsd and .vdx Visio files, you can edit it, and then you can export it back to Visio's format.

Comment: I noticed you've been answering a number of questions about Visio with a recommendation to try Lucidchart. Are you by any chance affiliated with that product? Because if so, [you must disclose that fact in your answers](http://superuser.com/faq#promotion).