# What's the recommended free software to draw data structures?

Tags: software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visio alternatives](https://superuser.com/questions/29060/visio-alternatives)

I don't know such a tool yet,

and it's sometimes hard to work if I don't draw it out..

Anyone can recommend a good candidiate?

Comment: @slhck ,Visio is for drawing UML,I just need to draw data structures(the `struct` in c).

Comment: @Asker: whats the difference between a struct in UML and in C?

Comment: @akira,In UML,you can't represent the exact location of each data structure.

Answer (score 1):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is one possibility

[image: Data Structures Graph]

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921931/visualising-c-structs

Comment: I heard its arrows are NOT sticky, that's bad!

Comment: @Asker: GraphViz draws directed graphs. The nodes and arrows are positioned by the software. GraphViz attempts to optimise the layout by minimising crossings (you can add constraints). Stickiness of arrows is not a concept that applies here.

Comment: Anyway that's bad user experience IMO.

Comment: @Asker: what is?

Comment: The arrow should be stick when I move the blocks around.

Comment: @Asker: With GraphViz. arrows are always attached to blocks. You define the graphs textually, not by drawing. I'll add an appropriate example when I get time.

Comment: if you mean connectors, yes, graphviz uses them.